# Including and referencing 3rd party libraries in a GAE project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For my gae python project, I'd like to import an external library named 'vobject'. What's the correct way to import it in my .py files?

The project's readme says that in order to install it, you need to run

```
  python setup.py install
```

Additionally, vobject requires the 'dateutil' package.

Since this is going to run on GAE, I thought I should copy both libs over into my project instead of running the install script to make use of it in my code.

But I'm getting a bunch of import errors and I'm not sure what the correct convention is for external gae/python libs.

```
utc = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
## error produced:
File "myGaeProject/external/vobject/icalendar.py", line 47, in <module>
NameError: name 'dateutil' is not defined
```

Because of the way I've structured my project, I changed icalendar.py's import structure from:

```
import dateutil.rrule
import dateutil.tz
```

to:

```
import external.dateutil.rrule
import external.dateutil.tz
```

I also tried:

```
from external.dateutil import *
```

What's the correct import mechanism for a project structured like so:

```
-myGaeProject

--external
----__init__.py    

----dateutil
------__init__.py
------tz.py
------rrule.py
------[more dateutil files]

----vobject
------__init__.py
------base.py    
------icalendar.py    

--handlers
------__init__.py
------mainHandler.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify the library. If you want to put all your libraries in `external`, you need to add `external` to your python path before you attempt to import libraries from there:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'external'))
import some_external_library
```

Comment: Would you do this in just the one py file or in all files that include an external lib?

Comment: @Dan Generally you'd put this in a module that you import everywhere you want to be able to import external libraries (or somewhere you know will run before those, such as in your script handler).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `from external import dateutil` if external is missing an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. __init__.py exists in external as well. Question fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The good way is to use zipimport, you can check the project jaikuengine they are a lot of good things about that.

http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/source/browse/trunk/build.py

In Jaiku, all external libs are stocked in the directory `vendor` but if you see the app.yaml, all files in `vendor` are skipped.
Jaiku uses a script to build a zip of each libs in vendor and put it to the root of the project before the deployment or when the dev_server is launched.

With that, you don't need to fix the path of your libs.

**EDIT** an example to load all zipped archives
*Largely inspired from jaikuengine*:

```
def load_zipped(path='.'):
  for x in os.listdir(path):
    if x.endswith('.zip'):
      if not any([y.endswith(x) for y in sys.path]):
        sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('%s/%s') % (path, x))
```

Comment: You don't have to use zipimport.

Comment: Yes, use zipimport is not explicit: http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html#examples

Comment: No, what I mean is that using zipimport is orthogonal to the problem at hand.